# Does 100s of routes in ember affect performance of app

Tags: ember.js, seo

I am trying to create a product catalog application in emberjs with a Ruby on Rails backend serving all the product information.

In order to be a good SEO citizen and overall Google friendly I want to create routes in ember that are very descriptive. To do this I have chosen to use 2 properties that each product has. For example I chose `colour` and `shape` therefore I want to create routes that appear like this in the URL

```
www.mysqesomecatalog.com/product/red/square
www.myawesomecatalog.com/producs/square/red
```

Notice that the colour and the shape can be in either order so to achieve this I would need to create double the amount of routes to accommodate for the reverse pair.

What I have so far is an excessive number of routes that look like such:

```
this.route('red.square',  { path: '/products/red/square'  });
this.route('red.circle',  { path: '/products/red/circle'  });
this.route('blue.square', { path: '/products/blue/square' });
this.route('blue.circle', { path: '/products/blue/circle' });
this.route('square.red',  { path: '/products/square/red'  });
this.route('circle.red',  { path: '/products/circle/red'  });
this.route('square.blue', { path: '/products/square/blue' });
this.route('circle.blue', { path: '/products/circle/blue' });
...
...
```

I could potentially end up with 100s of routes in my ember router and this seems just silly. Does anybody know if this will affect performance? And ultimately are there any better ways to accomplish what I want?

I have toyed with the idea of using dynamic segments. Does this sound like a more feasible approach?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use dynamic segments?  `this.route('product-page',  { path: '/products/:color/:shape'  });`

Comment: I agree with dynamic segments. If the order isn't 100% predictble, perhaps /products/:property1/:property2?

Comment: So perhaps in this instance I may have to have two dynamic segments `this.route('colour', { path: '/products/c/:colour/:shape' })` & `this.route('shape', { path: '/products/s/:shape/:colour' })`. Obviously there has to be some way for ember to differentiate which route the user is attempting to access if they come directly from a URL which is why I have put the `/c/` and `/s/`. Thought?

Comment: I'm not convinced it's that good for SEO to do this, and you could have your server redirect one of them if this is pre-existing. But absent those concerns, yes, that seems ideal.

Comment: I'd also separate out EVERYTHING in the route into a top level component, using the controller for as little as possible.  Then you can reuse everything between the two.